# Compare tables efficiently

Tags: c#, compare

I want to compare two tables. I want to get an output like Equal/Unequal if rows x and y aren't equal. So everything possible should be reported but I don't know what the best way is. All I need is some examples to get a better idea then that:

My `TableModel` class:

```
class TableModel {
    private string tableName;
    private string[] headers;
    private string[] keys;

    public int RowCount { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get { return tableName; } set { this.tableName = value; } }
    public string[] Headers { get { return headers; } set { this.headers = value; } }
    public string[] Keys { get { return keys; } set { this.keys = value; } }
}
```

My `Compare` class:

```
private void StartCompare() {
        int counter = 0;

        foreach(string nkey in newModel.Keys){
            foreach(string ckey in currentModel.Keys){
                if(!nkey.Equals(ckey)){
                    counter++;
                } 
            }

            if(currentModel.Keys.Length -1 != counter){
                //row not found in currentModel
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your requirement isn't clear.

Comment: edited: hope clear now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of comparing arrays (`String[] Keys` in the question) I suggest using `HashSet<String>` since hash-based search is faster - O(1) in comparison with O(N); like that:

```
HashSet<String> newKeys = new HashSet<String>(newModel.Keys);
HashSet<String> currentKeys = new HashSet<String>(currentModel.Keys);

foreach (String key in newKeys)
  if (!currentKeys.Contains(key)) {
    // The key is in the new model, but not in the current one

    //TODO: put the relevant code here:
  }

foreach (String key in currentKeys)
  if (!newKeys.Contains(key)) {
    // The key is in the current model, but not in the new one

    //TODO: put the relevant code here: 
  }
```

Comment: thats very helpful thanks!
Now if i have the not found rows how can I check if one row is similar to the notfound row?

Comment: @Ams1: what is *similar*, e.g. is `1` *similar* to `2`? to `12`?

Comment: Row1: 1,c,x,y
Row2: 1,c,x,z
Row 2 and 1 is similar or would that be bad to do?

Comment: @Ams: if you're looking for *edit distance* you should place it inside `if` (`//TODO...`) so whenever *key* is not found, scan rows? keys? and find the one with minimal edit distance

Comment: ok, thank you for the awnser.